# AES encryption doesnt accept special characters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, encryption, aes

When i decrypt .xlsx or .csv with AES in Asp.Net Core 3.1, it doesn´t return special characters (á, é, í,ó,ú) those are replaced with a "?".

This is my code. Example: José González after decrypt returns Jos? Gonz?alez

```
 public static void encrypt(IFormFile uploadFile)
    {
        
        ICryptoTransform transform = _crypt_provider.CreateEncryptor();

        //Extraer los datos del csv en un string
        string text;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(uploadFile.OpenReadStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            // lectura del contenido del archivo
            text = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }


        byte[] encrypted_bytes = transform.TransformFinalBlock(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text) , 0, text.Length);

        string textoEncrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted_bytes);

        Debug.WriteLine($"El texto ingresado = {text} \nEl texto encriptado = {textoEncrypted}");

        File.WriteAllText(uploadFile.FileName, textoEncrypted);
      
    }


 public static string decrypt(IFormFile uploadFile)
    {
        
        string text;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(uploadFile.OpenReadStream()))//, Encoding.UTF8
        {
            // lectura del contenido del archivo
            text = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        ICryptoTransform transform = _crypt_provider.CreateDecryptor();

        byte[] encrypted_bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(text);

        byte[] dencrypted_bytes = transform.TransformFinalBlock(encrypted_bytes, 0, encrypted_bytes.Length);

        string textoDesencriptado = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(dencrypted_bytes);

        //File.WriteAllText(uploadFile.FileName, textoDesencriptado);

        Debug.WriteLine($"El texto ingresado = {text} \nEl texto desencriptado = {textoDesencriptado}");

        return textoDesencriptado;
    }
```

Comment: Don't use ASCIIEncoding, use UTF8Encoding instead.

Comment: It looks as if you have commented out the UTF8 encoding part.